# Android/Java. Какой лэйоут и вьювы использовать?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

На рисунке вот контейнер

[image: рис1]

Какими вьювами можно спроектировать следующий макет? кнопка, текствьюв, прозрачный имейдж или стиль?

+

Нужно запрограммировать чтобы при событии OnFling() этот желтый слой перемещался (анимация) вправо по контейнеру.. и становилось так:

[image: рис2]

надписи при этом остаются на местах не моргают, не исчезают.

Какой лэйоут использовать для контейнера и Какими компонентами это все можно сделать?

Comment: вы шутите? Это элементарно решается гуглом. Вам нужен элемент switch. Как его стилизовать в первой же ссылке описано: [клац](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118050/how-can-i-style-an-android-switch), ну а чтобы сделать текст видимым всегда, смотрим [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356349/switch-issue-only-one-option-visible)

Comment: Нее, свитч не пойдет.., там плавный переход должен быть. т.е желтый слой.как бы движется внутри контейнера (плывет)... а не так резко..

Comment: вообще-то как раз switch это и реализует, есть библиотеки для красивых анимаций свичей. Если хотите свой велосипед - вперед. Свой layout с набором кастомных View, для каждого делаете OnTouchListener, описываете анимации и будет как надо, но кода - много.

Answer (score 3):

По всей видимости тут использовался переключатель (toggle), можете наследоваться от ToogleButton, можете поискать кастомное решение для более старых версий, а можете сделать своё, как вы изначально спрашивали.
если делать по вашей задумке, то тут набор такой:
RelativeLayout, внутри него первым делом добавляете ImageView, как у вас на картинке, т.е. фон, далее добавляете 2 TextView, порядок добавления необходимо сохранять, т.к. при таком порядке фон будет находиться сзади. Далее добавляете анимацию ко всему этому и прикрепляете обработчик нажатия на RelativeLayout, далее делаете 2 анимации для сдвига заднего фона (влево, вправо), переопределяете OnClick() для вашего обработчика и выполняете анимацию в зависимости от состояния и плов готов.
Забыл ещё добавить, что изменяйте текст TextView при обработке нажатия, можете текже прилепить обработки на анимацию, чтобы изменять цвет в конце анимации, в общем как сами захотите, так и будет работать